# Como fazer uma pesquisa em um conjunto passando o caractere como parâmetro em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algoritmo-de-busca

Possuo duas funções distintas, uma faz pesquisa por um id(funciona) outra faz pesquisa por um caractere letra(funciona). Preciso que essas duas funções atuem juntas,como?

Quando eu selecionar o id, que retornar o conjunto que pertencem ao tal id tem que ser possível fazer outra pesquisa neste conjunto, agora per *letter*.
Não sei como juntar esses métodos.

```
$scope.byLetter = function (letter) {
    $scope.unitsPromise =
      $http
        .get('/api/units.json?letter=' + letter)
        .success(function (data) {
          $scope.total_pages = data.total_pages;
          $scope.units = data.units;
        });
  };
```

---

```
$scope.$watch('organ_id', function (newValue, oldValue, letter) {
    if (newValue != null && newValue != '' && letter == null) {
      $scope.unitsPromise =
        $http
          .get('/api/units.json?organ_id=' + newValue)
          .success(function (data) {
            $scope.units = data.units;
          });
    };
 }, true);
```

Essas são os dois métodos, o que pesquisa por letra e o que relaciona o conjunto ao id do órgão.